# I got the error code -1073741571 in my snake game

Tags: c++

I'm making a snake game and it's basically done; however sometimes when I run it it works at first then clears (that might be in my code, it has a lot of clears) and returns error code -1073741571.
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "windows.h" 
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool goTo(point p,vector<point>& snek)
{
    bool flag=false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < snek.size(); i++)
    {
        if (p.x == snek[i].x && p.y == snek[i].y)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    for (int i=snek.size()-1; i >0; i--)
    {
        snek[i] = snek[i - 1];
    }
    snek[0] = p;
    return false;
}
void makeFood(point& apple, vector<point> snek)
{
    bool appleValid = true;
    apple.x = (rand() % 19) + 1;
    apple.y = (rand() % 19) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < snek.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (apple.x == snek[i].x && apple.y == snek[i].y)
        {
            appleValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!appleValid)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        makeFood(apple,snek);
    }

}
int main()
{
    vector<point> snek;
    snek.push_back({ 10,10 });
    snek.push_back({ 10,9 });
    snek.push_back({ 10,8 });
    snek.push_back({ 10,7 });
    int highscore= 0, score;
    bool tutorial = false;
    bool p = false;
    char move = 'w';
    char sure = 'f';
    string board[21][21];
    int direction=2;
    point apple;
    apple.x = rand() % 20;
    apple.y = rand() % 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = "  ";
        }
    }
    bool loss = false;
    while (true)
    {
        score = snek.size() - 4;
        bool  appleEaten = false;
        srand(time(NULL));
        if (snek[0].x == 0 )
            loss = true;
        if (snek[0].x == 20 )
            loss = true;
        if (snek[0].y == 0 )
            loss = true;
        if (snek[0].y == 20 )
            loss = true;
        if (loss)
        {
            system("CLS");
            if (score > highscore)
            {
                highscore = score;
            }
            cout << "You lost with a score of " << snek.size() - 4 << endl;
            cout << "Your highscore for this session is " << highscore<<endl;
            cout << "Press any key to play again" << endl;
            cout << "Press RMB to quit" << endl;
            while (true)
            {
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON))
                {
                    system("CLS");
                    cout << "Are you sure you want to quit? Your highscore for this session will be reset" << endl;
                    cout << "Press Q to quit and P to play again" << endl;
                    sure = _getch();
                    if (sure == 'q' || sure == 'Q')
                    {
                        _Exit(0);
                    }
                    if (sure == 'p' || sure == 'P')
                    {
                        p = true;
                    }
                }
                if (_kbhit() || p)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                        {
                            board[i][j] = "  ";
                        }
                    }
                    snek.clear();
                    snek.push_back({ 10,10 });
                    snek.push_back({ 10,9 });
                    snek.push_back({ 10,8 });
                    snek.push_back({ 10,7 });
                    loss = false;
                    p = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Sleep(100);
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            move = _getch();
        }
        system("CLS");
        switch (move) 
        {
        case 'w':
            loss = goTo({ (snek[0].x - 1),snek[0].y }, snek);
            Sleep(10);
            break;
        case 'a':
            loss = goTo({ snek[0].x ,(snek[0].y - 1) }, snek);
            Sleep(10);
            break;
        case 's':
            loss = goTo({ (snek[0].x + 1),snek[0].y }, snek);
            Sleep(10);
            break;
        case'd':
            loss = goTo({ snek[0].x ,(snek[0].y + 1) }, snek);
            Sleep(10);
            break;
        }
        board[apple.x][apple.y] = " 0";
        for (int k = 0; k < snek.size() - 1; k++)
        {
            board[snek[k].x][snek[k].y] = " *";
            board[snek[snek.size() - 1].x] [snek[snek.size() - 1].y] = "  ";
        }
        if (apple.x == snek[0].x && apple.y == snek[0].y)
        {
            snek.push_back({snek[snek.size()-1].x+1,snek[snek.size() - 1].y});
            appleEaten = true;
        }
        if (appleEaten)
        {
            makeFood(apple,snek);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            board[0][i] = "--";
            board[20][i] = "--";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            board[i][0] = '|';
            board[i][20] = '|';
        }
        if (!tutorial)
        {
            cout << "You are a snake." << endl;
            cout << "Your body looks like this" << endl;
            cout << "*****" << endl;
            cout << "Move with WASD" << endl;
            cout << "If you eat the apples, which look like this " << endl << "0" << endl;
            cout << "You get bigger. If you try to eat yourself or run into walls, you lose" << endl;
            cout << "Click RMB to begin";
            while (true)
            {
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON))
                {
                    system("CLS");
                    tutorial = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
            {
                cout << board[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Score: " << score;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Most of the time it works fine, only sometimes I get the error
EDIT: The stack overflow is in `int main()`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207719/discussion-on-question-by-polar-bear-i-got-the-error-code-1073741571-in-my-snak).

Answer (score 1):

Let’s take a closer look at your `makeFood` function:

```
void makeFood(point& apple, vector<point> snek)
{
    bool appleValid = true;
    apple.x = (rand() % 19) + 1;
    apple.y = (rand() % 19) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < snek.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (apple.x == snek[i].x && apple.y == snek[i].y)
        {
            appleValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!appleValid)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        makeFood(apple,snek);
    }

}
```

Your if statement makes it so that `makeFood()` is called again when the apple is at the snakes position, but using `srand(time(NULL))` will put the apple back into the same place, which calls the function again and again for an infinite amount of time. Remove `srand(time(NULL))` in the `if(!appleValid)` and your program shouldn’t have the issue because you only need to seed random.

if you can, try to convert your random functions to the `<random>` header, but it should work fine with `rand` as well :)

Comment: I would use the <random> header but I have no idea how to use it..

Comment: No offense, but the stack overflow is in main(), I just found out

Comment: could you elaborate? It might just be because you're calling the function in `main()`